# Change the day from where the week starts in bucket in Splunk

Tags: aggregate, splunk, dayofweek, bucket

I am running this query in splunk which bucketizes the data on a weekly basis , based on the field "impact_start" and gives me the output. But the problem is that the start of the week in the output is Thursday rather than Monday.

Is there any way i can change the start of the week to Monday instead of Thursday?

```
 search index=* impact=1 OR impact=2 product_line=* | eval time = round( strptime(impact_start,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 0 )| where time >= 1473328728 AND time<=1476352728| bucket time span=7d | stats values(number) as incident_name by time
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck - If you look at the strftime spec, Monday is considered the start of the week
http://strftime.org/

So you could try this: (untested)

```
index=* impact=1 OR impact=2 product_line=*
| eval time = round( strptime(impact_start,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 0 )
| where time >= 1473328728 AND time<=1476352728
| eval week = strftime(impact_start,"%Y %w")
| stats values(number) as incident_name by week
```